# Is a wood shed with 12mm walls worth it?

Tags: woodworking, outdoor, shed

I have a plot of land in Spain where the winter is a bit windy and the summer is quite hot. I was about to buy a container for storing my junk, however due to its price and the infrastructure it requires, I decided to leave it to next year and use a small wood shed meanwhile.

There are many sheds which are cheap but their wall thickness is 12mm. Is this acceptable? How long will it last? I've seen many reviews but none of them are clear in regards to this topic.

Comment: Are you referring to the wall *sheathing*? What's the alternative thickness? What material?

Comment: they are made of wood. Alternatives start with 19mm but they are more expensive (of course).

Comment: There is not enough information in the question to provide a good answer. I have assembled some of those kit sheds (helped friends) they look nice and can last year's but what they paid I could buy the lumber and build one using full sized studs the kits used 2x3 in both kits. The advantage to the kits is they go up faster since the walls and roof were already assembled. If it will last depends on the materials in the kit chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After further contemplation I suspect that we're discussing *siding*, not sheathing. The latter is installed over framing and under siding. Siding is probably plywood or pressed fiber hardboard.

Most sheds (and indeed most homes) in my region are built using 7/16" (about 11mm) oriented strand board (OSB) wall sheathing underneath some sort of siding. This is standard. Wood panel siding is rarely used anymore *except* on sheds, but 1/2" (about 12mm) siding panels of good quality provide plenty of strength and durability when applied over good framing.

How long it lasts depends on now it's cared for and protected. It should be primed and painted or otherwise sealed initially and every few years thereafter. Ideally all edges are sealed, particularly the bottom where rain splash will soak into the wood, causing swelling, decomposition, and eventually rot. Plywood or hardboard siding that's cared for and doesn't reside in perpetually wet locations can last 10 years or more.

Comment: +1 for priming edges and mentioning maintenance. I’d add that the thickness of sheathing or siding is all based on spacing of studs (supports).